# Sum multidimensional array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I vertically sum a multidimensional array like this:

```
[
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [2,4,6]
]
```

To get this results:

```
[14, 19, 24]
```

---

I did it for 2 arrays, but i dont know how to implement the same solution for `n` arrays.

This is how i do it for 2 arrays

```
var sum = array1.map(function (num, index) {
  return num + array2[index];
});
```

Being array1 and array2 the two arrays i want to sum. 
So how can i do the same for a multidimensional `n` length array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use `.reduce`:

```js
const input = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [2,4,6]
];

const sumArr = input.reduce((partials, arr) => {
  arr.forEach((num, i) => {
    if (!partials[i]) partials[i] = 0;
    partials[i] += num;
  });
  return partials;
}, []);

console.log(sumArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `reduce`.

This is assuming that every nested array has the same length.

```js
var array = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

var result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  c.forEach((n, i) => (a[i] = (a[i] || 0) + n));
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```